# error:400 Bad Request Unfortunately we could not process your transaction. There was a problem with: No payment data received

Tags: payfast

I used payfast as my payment gateway in my website, if am testing payfast on their test engine it works fine when I post values to their engine, but when am using their engine that is not for testing it gives me that error saying "No payment data received"[there is an error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ixB.png)

Comment: This sounds like the incorrect payment URL is being used, which causes PayFast to then redirect to the correct one (if possible), and upon redirecting, the payload is lost. The correct URL is `https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process` as per their docs. A common mistake people make when moving from the sandbox URL to the live URL, is leaving out the `www`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error as well, turns out I was just leaving out the `www` as [Daniel_ZA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349258/daniel-za) pointed out.

```
<form action="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" method="POST"></form>
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes :)